# How activate the GNOME ENVIOREMENT in SLES 11 SP4?

Tags: gnome

i am trying to run the gnome envirioment in an SLES 11 SP4 instance, i do the following:

First i install the package:

```
zypper -n install -t pattern x11 gnome
```

And make the next changes:

In window manager script

vi /etc/sysconfig/windowmanager

at line 18 change

```
 DEFAULT_WM="gnome"
```

At display manager script

vi /etc/sysconfig/displaymanager

at line 7 change

```
DISPLAYMANAGER="gdm"
```

Change to graphical login

```
vi /etc/inittab

at line 20 change to graphical login

id:5:initdefault:
```

I made a rebbot but whwn the instance get up, the gnome enviorement it does not run, only i have the CLI.

Any help to solve this topic will be weel recieved.

Thanks

Comment: Can you put any x11 log in the question? Where do you running your SLES? You tried to run startx command?

Comment: Hi Angel i am running an instance at google cloud, SLES 11 SP4, when i run the startx command i get the next:                                         
bizs:~ # startx
No startx installed
So i do the next:
 zypper install -t pattern x11 gnome

Comment: The system install all the packages (around 1.6 Gb) and do it correctly, so then i do the next:
In window manager script
 vi /etc/sysconfig/windowmanager
 at line 18 i change
  DEFAULT_WM="gnome"
At display manager script
 vi /etc/sysconfig/displaymanager
 at line 7 change
 DISPLAYMANAGER="gdm"
also Change to graphical login
 vi /etc/inittab
 at line 20 change to graphical login
 id:5:initdefault:

Comment: Then i run startx again and i get this:
bizs:~ # startx
xauth:  creating new authority file /root/.serverauth.17650
xauth:  creating new authority file /root/.Xauthority
xauth:  creating new authority file /root/.Xauthority
X.Org X Server 1.6.5
Release Date: 2009-10-11

Comment: X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: openSUSE SUSE LINUX
Current Operating System: Linux bizs 3.0.101-104-default #1 SMP Mon Jun 19 11:35:24 UTC 2017 (fa1fcfd) x86_64
Build Date: 06 July 2017  11:56:37AM
 
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.

Comment: (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Aug 10 04:31:00 2017
(==) Using default built-in configuration (21 lines)
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
(EE) No devices detected.
Fatal server error:
no screens found
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
giving up.
xinit:  No such file or directory (errno 2):  unable to connect to X server
xinit:  No such process (errno 3):  Server error.

Comment: and in the log you can see the next:

        compiled for 1.6.5, module version = 1.13.0
        Module class: X.Org Server Extension
        ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension RECORD
(II) LoadModule: "dri"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules//extensions/libdri.so
(II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.6.5, module version = 1.0.0
        ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
(II) LoadModule: "dri2"

Comment: (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules//extensions/libdri2.so
(II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.6.5, module version = 1.1.0
        ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension DRI2
(II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules//drivers/fbdev_drv.so
(II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.6.5, module version = 0.4.1
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 5.0

Comment: (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules//drivers/vesa_drv.so
(II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.6.5, module version = 2.2.1
        Module class: X.Org Video Driver
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 5.0
(II) LoadModule: "mouse"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules//input/mouse_drv.so
(II) Module mouse: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.6.5, module version = 1.4.0
        Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
        ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 4.0

Comment: (II) LoadModule: "kbd"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules//input/kbd_drv.so
(II) Module kbd: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.6.5, module version = 1.3.2
        Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
        ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 4.0
(II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
(II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
(II) Primary Device is: PCI 00@00:03:0

Comment: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
(II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
(II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
(II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/linux//libfbdevhw.so
(II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.6.5, module version = 0.0.2
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 5.0

Comment: (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
(EE) No devices detected.

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Comment: I hope this help, i am just new on this topic.